# App Intent with Eddystone Beacons and Nearby

Tags: android, android-intent, eddystone

I would like to open a certain instagram profile in the App when a user clicks on a Nearby Notification.

I have three fields to fill out:

- Intent scheme
- Intent path
- App package name

The package name is fairly clear (com.instagram.android). But when I only fill this field, the app store opens first. There I have to click on "open" to open Instagram. What am I doing wrong? The only app intent tutorials I found are about direct app integration and not of much use.

Comment: What values are you putting in for all three fields when it opens the Play Store and not the app?

Comment: Only the package name.

Answer (score 1):

The App intent only works for apps that have been published on the Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add some content at your app like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data
        android:host="scan"
        android:pathPrefix="/profile/foo"
        android:scheme="fb"/>
</intent-filter>
```

You can see more information [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format).